# How to fix cbind function?

Tags: r

I am using field spectra program found here https://github.com/serbinsh/R-FieldSpectra . In the second step, when I run

```
m = cbind(CF_690, CF_740, Chl_a_b, NDVI, NDWI, PRI, PRI2, SR, WBI) 
plotnames = spectra[,1]
specindices = cbind(plotnames, m)
```

I then receive this error "
Warning message:
In cbind(plotnames, m) :
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)"

Anything helps, I'm pretty new with R. Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate in your question, what the variable `m` is. Most likely `m` and `plotnames` have different lengths.

Comment: Is there a way to combine m and plotnames even though they have different lengths?

Comment: R tries to automatically match different lengths when possible, e.g. if one length is the multiple of another length. Somehow this is not the case with your data.

Comment: I have just seen, you are using `cbind` for `m`. This creates a 1xn matrix. However, `plotnames` is a nx1 column. Just use the function `c` instead of `cbind` for `m`